# Remove Key and value in a nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the below nested dictionary:

```
config = {'trainsets': {'datasets': 
{'coco': {'root': 'path1', 'anno': 'anno1', 'num_use': 1, 'frame_range': 2}, 
'ytb': {'root': 'path2', 'anno': 'anno2', 'num_use': 1, 'frame_range': 3}, 
'abc': {'root': 'path3', 'anno': 'anno3', 'num_use': 1, 'frame_range': 4}}}}
```

I need to delete the element 'num_use' for **ONLY** 'coco'

```
config = {'trainsets': {'datasets': 
{'coco': {'root': 'path1', 'anno': 'anno1', 'frame_range': 2}, 
'ytb': {'root': 'path2', 'anno': 'anno2', 'num_use': 1, 'frame_range': 3}, 
'abc': {'root': 'path3', 'anno': 'anno3', 'num_use': 1, 'frame_range': 4}}}}
```

I tried the below but its not working:

```
del config['trainsets']['datasets']["coco"]["num_use"]
```

Comment: Can't reproduce. It does work for me. However, the proper way would be to use `.pop`: `config['trainsets']['datasets']["coco"].pop("num_use")`

Comment: I need only "num_use" removed from coco. I need other elements present in coco

Comment: So call `pop` on `["coco"]`.... see updated comment

Answer (score 1):

`config['trainsets']['datasets']["coco"].pop("num_use")` will surely work